# How to make 32bit and 64bit Delphi Applications in DELPHI XE6?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe6

we are going to buy DELPHI XE6. Now I have 32bit code from Delphi 7 which I would like to adapt to 64bit and 32bit in Delphi XE6. Where can I select wether I want 64bit EXEs or/and 32bit EXEs in Delphi XE6? 
Thanks
Walter

Comment: download the demo and try for yourself, or wait until you have bought it and try for yourself :) I would imagine 32bit applications would be the standard setting and there would likely an option to switch to 64bit.

Comment: Did it not occur to you to read the docs?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan thanks, but I do not have it yet, but Remy has given me all what I need. thanks to Remy

Comment: The documentation is public on the web. This is not the way to evaluate a product. Get the trial and read the docs.

Comment: My guess is that the Unicode migration that Remy mentions is going to take you a while, before you get around to the 64 bit.  Do the Unicode part FIRST even though it's the SECOND part of Remy's answer.  I recommend you find Nick Hodge's Delphi Unicode stuff, and Marco Cantu's Delphi 2009 book.

Comment: @WarrenP thanks, I have found Nicks stuff. Could you tell me how to enable the $IFDEF in a part of my (copied) source? I have  {$IFDEF UniCode}StrPos (regparse^, XIgnoredChars) <> nil
                  {$ELSE}regparse^ in XIgnoredChars{$ENDIF}
     
       So as I see the part of the coude is unicode compatible. but I get the E2010 INkomp Types PWideChar and CHAR.

Comment: Yeah. NO. Read more before diving in.  You are just going to make a mess until you develop a clue.

Comment: Start with Marco's whitepaper. Read it. Understand it. Then think about porting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Read Embarcadero's documentation:

[64-bit Windows Application Development](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/64-bit_Windows_Application_Development)

[Converting 32-bit Delphi Applications to 64-bit Windows](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/Converting_32-bit_Delphi_Applications_to_64-bit_Windows)

[Importing or Migrating Existing Projects into RAD Studio](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/Importing_or_Migrating_Existing_Projects_into_RAD_Studio)

Since you are porting from Delphi 7 to XE6, you will also have to deal with the Unicode migration as well (which was introduced in Delphi 2009):

[Migration to Unicode](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/Unicode_in_RAD_Studio)

[Enabling Applications for Unicode](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/Enabling_Applications_for_Unicode)

Comment: Thanks, must I compile twice to get 64bit and 32bit target paltforms by selecting  the target platform (bold) in the Project Manager, or are the 2 EXEs created at once when I add 64 and 32 as target patforms. (In other words: Must I select the active target platform manually and compile for each separately?)

Comment: @Walter No. You can compile from the command line in an automated way. Building from the IDE is for dev not for release building.

Comment: There are build groups too to get this with one action, no need for command line

Comment: @Sir do they allow specification of targets and build configs? And why be scared of the command line. Automation is desirable. Who builds with a mouse?!

Comment: @David Yes they do and I am not scared, but I do not like leaving home just to switch the lights on - yes I am lazy :)

Comment: @Sir using a scripted build takes less effort than from ide!

Comment: @David a small couple of clicks against your script building :o)

Comment: @David Heffernan - "Who builds with a mouse?!" - anybody who has ever played Minecraft.

Comment: @Sir You win if you only build your project once. I win if you build it repeatedly. I win if you want to be 100% sure that the right thing was built.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Using a Build Group allows one-click compiling of multiple configurations at a time. If you need to make a config change (add/remove platforms, etc), that can be done visually within the IDE. With your approach, you have to modify your script accordingly. The only benefit I see to scripting is to automate background compiling, but if you are actively writing code then one-click Build Group compiling works just as well.

Comment: @Remy Scripting allows zero-click compilation. If you can't see the benefits of scripting and automation then I'm not going to attempt to persuade you of them.

Comment: Build groups and scripts have both pros and cons - I use build groups and can live with the cons. There is nothing wrong with scripts and they are much more flexible than the build groups (fi creating a setup from all compiled files). So it really depends on the needs.

Comment: @Sir Build groups (http://www.uweraabe.de/Blog/2013/01/07/do-you-know-build-groups/) do seem quite neat. Scripted builds are still very important. For instance, I have a scheduled task that checks out head from repo, performs build, runs regression tests and delivers report of any failures. This runs daily, automatically and gives a heads up on breaking changes. Scripting essential, obviously.

Comment: @David that is what I mean talking about the pros and cons. Scripts are much more powerful than the groups. Everyone has to decide which is better to use to reach the desired goal. For a real decision you have to know your possibilities to choose from and the limitations of each